# How to Check if a Generic Type is IComparable then Compare if so?

Tags: c#, generics, icomparable

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like the pseudo-code below:

```
private void test<T>(T a, T b)
{
    if (a is IComparable<T> && b is IComparable<T>)
    {
        int result = a.CompareTo(b);
        // do something with the result
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that in C# ?

Comment: have you tried `int result = (a as IComparable<T>).CompareTo((b as IComparable<T>));`?

Comment: try `if(a is iComparable<T> comparableA [...]`

Comment: Note that the `CompareTo` method requires that its parameter be a `T`. There's no requirement that it be cast to `IComparable<T>`. It's implied by it being the same type as  implements the `CompareTo` method. (A long way of saying no need to duplicate the logic for `b`, just pass `b`)

Comment: @Felk ```int result = (a as IComparable<T>).CompareTo(b);``` seems to compile, I'll try to run it when I get home

Comment: Update: ```int result = (a as IComparable<T>).CompareTo(b);``` works, but I've accepted Pavel Anikhouski's answer because it is cleaner I think. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`is` type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) to assign the result to a variable and use it to call `Compare`. You also don't need to cast `b` to `IComparable<T>`, since `CompareTo` accepts parameter of `T` type (and `b` is `T` already)

```cs
if (a is IComparable<T> comparable)
{
    int result = comparable.CompareTo(b);
    // do something with the result
}
```

Another option is to apply a generic constraint with `IComparable<T>` interface

```cs
private void test<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var result = a.CompareTo(b);
    // do something with the result
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is cleaner than the one I've commented in the original post :)